# "register to" vs "register for"

Tags: prepositions

Which one of the following two sentences is more accurate in regard to the prepositions usage "to vs for".

> I want to register to the meeting.
> I want to register for the meeting.

If both are correct (Till today, Google found 84,700,000 results for "register to", and 118,000,000 results for "register for"), then what is the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use "register for" when followed by a noun:

> Register **for** the meeting.  Register **for** a chance to win.

Use "register to" when followed by a verb:

> Register **to** vote.  Register **to** work at the fundraiser.

Comment: Very late comment, but what about 'register with'? I would *register with* a company or organisation. what are the rules on that?

Comment: Also used with a noun. You register **for** an event or an activity. You register **with** an organization or a person or group of people.

Answer (score -2):

> I would sign up for the meeting. (In standard American English)
> I would register for the meeting!
> I would go to the meeting.
> I would not be late for the meeting.
> The donuts are for the meeting.
> Are you going to the meeting?

I should add that "I would register to attend the meeting." Certainly what is written prior to or after the preposition can alter the meaning to make it more grammatical. Whether an anaphoric reference or a collocation--i.e., certain words habitually appear together.